# How to stub a "wrapper" function using Sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, sinon

I'm setting up a Lambda function (node.js) and for example's sake, we'll keep it minimal.

```
module.exports = (event, context, callback) {
  console.log("hello world")
}
```

However, I've created a function to wrap the lambda function that allows me to perform some functions that are required before each Lambda executes (I have a collection of Lambda functions that are wired up using their [Serverless Application Model (SAM)](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model)). It also allows me to consolidate some of the logging and error handling across each function.

```
// hook.js
const connect = fn => (event, context, callback) => {
  someFunction()
    .then(() => fn(event, context, callback))
    .then(res => callback(null, res))
    .catch(error => {
      // logging
      callback(error)
    })
}

module.exports = { connect }

// index.js
const Hook = require("./hook")

exports.handler = Hook.connect((event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("hello world")
})
```

The logic is working well and Lambda is processing it successfully. However, I'm trying to stub this `Hook.connect` function using [SinonJS](https://sinonjs.org) and in need of some guidance.

I simply want to stub it to return a resolved promise, that way we can proceed to handle the code within each Lambda function (`fn(event, context, callback)`).

```
const sinon = require("sinon")
const Hook = require("./hook")
const { handler } = require("./index")
const event = {} // for simplicity sake
const context = {} // for simplicity sake
const callback = {} // for simplicity sake

describe("Hello", () => {
  let connectStub

  beforeEach(() => {
    connectStub = sinon.stub(Hook, "connect").callsFake()

  afterEach(() => {
    connectStub.restore()
  })

  it("works", () => {
    const results = handler(event, context, callback)
    // assert
  })
})
```

I've tried a few different methods, from the basic, `sinon.stub(Hook, "connect")`, to the more complicated where I'm trying to stub private functions inside of the `hook.js` file using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire).

Any help would be appreciated -- thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working test:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const Hook = require('./hook');

const event = {}; // for simplicity sake
const context = {}; // for simplicity sake
const callback = {}; // for simplicity sake

describe('Hello', () => {

  let handler, connectStub;
  before(() => {
    connectStub = sinon.stub(Hook, 'connect');
    connectStub.callsFake(fn => (...args) => fn(...args));  // create the mock...
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./index')];  // (in case it's already cached)
    handler = require('./index').handler;  // <= ...now require index.js
  });

  after(() => {
    connectStub.restore();  // restore Hook.connect
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./index')];  // remove the modified index.js
  });

  it('works', () => {
    const results = handler(event, context, callback);  // it works!
    // assert
  });
});
```

**Details**

`index.js` calls `Hook.connect` to create its exported `handler` *as soon as it runs*, and it runs *as soon as it is `required`*...

...so the mock for `Hook.connect` needs to be in place *before* `index.js` is `required`:

[Node.js caches modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache), so this test also clears the Node.js cache before **and** after the test to ensure that `index.js` picks up the `Hook.connect` mock, and to ensure that the `index.js` with the mocked `Hook.connect` is *removed* from the cache in case the real `index.js` is needed later.

Comment: Really appreciate your time here as well as your thoughtful/detailed response. It works as expected!